# Excel 2007 VBA Workbook closing then reopening

Tags: vba, excel

In 2003 the workbook would just close. But now the same code is re-opening the workbook. There are some lines afterwards and then the sub ends. When the sub ends, the `workbook_open` event gets fired for the closed workbook, even though there is no code that opens any workbooks. The debugger is almost useless, it is not reproducing the bug if I execute everything step by step, in fact everything works fine when I use the debugger.

I use

`ActiveWorkbook.Close False`

For closing the workbook (from an add-in).

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out how to get both. Workbook_beforeclose cancels the scheduled ontime event by calling:

```
Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=Now(), Procedure:="Name", Schedule:=False
```

but otherwise the ontime event gets executed.

If the event does not get cancelled before beforeclose is called, the workbook will close then re-open to run the scheduled ontime event (because the workbook is opened so briefly that ontime doesn't get a chance to run before I need to close it).

Answer (score 0):

I added a slight amount of code for Excel 2007 because of the annoying ribbon and Microsoft getting rid of custom menus. To somewhat compensate for this, I wanted to have the add-ins tab in the ribbon always visible for convenience, but I was using Application.OnTime and sendkeys to do it (because Microsoft didn't bother including an API with the stupid ribbon...). Well OnTime seems to have been the root of my troubles.